# moved from cpanel to plesk and now php and curl not working that worked before

Tags: php, curl

This code was working on Cpanel, we moved to a dedicated server that has Plesk (I hate plesk, terrible, but it does work, but Curl not working...)...

This is the code that we have that worked flawlessly on Cpanel server:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$_pgCheck");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$pgCode = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

$_pgCheck url has this:

https://example.org/system/page/?var=longkey&user=username

something like that.
I had it output the domain it runs, and went there myself manually, and that page does output a response.

So the curl is not executing.

I added this line to test it:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "x.xx.xxx.xx") { // My IP address so only I see debuggin...
    if(!curl_init($ch)){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
    }
}
```

and it does die, but with this:

```
Error: "" - Code:
```

so no response in curl_error or curl_errno

How do I test it to figure out why it is not working?

Or do you see the error in the curl_init or curl_setopt I need to change?

UPDATE: I went into Plesk - Domains - domain name - PHP Settings and at the bottom, where I can add additional directives, I added:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

to make sure php compiled Curl.
but that did not change anything after I saved it.
Pretty sure after I saved it, Plesk restarted apache.

Thanks
-Rich

Comment: I did also try removing the verbose line: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
but that did not work either.

Comment: anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Do you see any error in /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/error_log or in /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. Do a phpinfo() on the new server and try to see if curl is enabled. You can just try to find curl in the output of phpinfo() (ctrl+f). If you cannot see curl than you probably need to install curl on that server's php. For that try googling - how to install curl module in php.

Comment: Checked, here are instance of curl: Configure Command:  '--with-curl=shared,/usr' 
and /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
and most important:
curl

cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.19.7
Age 3

does have this:
SSL Yes
SSPI No
Protocols tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps, scp, sftp
and this:
Debug No

so could that Debug be why the curl_error ones do not work?

Comment: So Curl is enabled though.

Comment: Any other ideas @Annop?

Comment: Do you see any error logs or anything where you are trying to execute the curl ? @RichardJones

Comment: No, nothing. :( @Anoop

Comment: Okay, I created a test, where I put a test php file: testingoutput.php that prints some test message, and a test api php file: testingapi.php that calls testingoutput.php via the curl. That worked. When I made it https:// call, so ssl, it does not work. So I think the problem is SSL, what do I do to make it work for SSL sites?

Comment: I added CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to it, as true and tried false, neither fix it where it can call SSL pages. :(